# Status bar and UIToolbar have two different colors

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, statusbar, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolbar which I have added to my UIViewController with a grey tint as its background color.  This matches the UINavigationViewController tint that the view came from.

The issue I am having is that the color of my status bar is staying white, to match the background of my UIView, while the UIToolbar is having a grey tint.  What I end up with is sort of ugly, and looks like this below.

[image: Status bar with different color than UIToolbar]

If possible, I'd like to have it match the behavior of my UINavigationViewController which looks like this.

[image: Status bar and UINavigationBar matching colors]

From what I can tell using Reveal App, the status bar is just being overlaid on to my UIView and so it's just taking the while color of my UIView as its background color.

One solution I can think of is to set the background of my UIView to match my UIToolBar and then add another UIView on top and keep that as white and add all of my UI elements back into that container.

That feels like a messy solution and was hoping there is something better I can do.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance